# How do I Send my pino logs from my nestjs application to application insights in azure

Tags: logging, nestjs, azure-application-insights, pino

This is my pino config

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Params } from 'nestjs-pino';

config();


const pinoConfig: Params = {
  pinoHttp:
    {
      level: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'debug' : 'info',
      formatters: {
        level: (label, number) => {
          return { level: label };
        },
      },
      customReceivedMessage: function(req, res) {
        return `request ${req.id} received: ${req.method} ${req.url}`;
      },
      customSuccessMessage: function(req, res) {
        return `${req.method} ${req.url} completed`;
      },
      customErrorMessage: function(req, res, err) {
        return `request ${req.id} to ${req.method} ${req.url} errored with status code: ${res.statusCode} message: ${err.message}}`;
      },
      
      transport: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
        ?
        {
          target: 'pino-pretty',
          options: {
            singleLine: true,
            ignore: 'pid,hostname,req.headers,req.remotePort,req.remoteAddress,req,res',

          }
        }
        : undefined
      ,
      
    }
};

export default pinoConfig;
```

And in my main.ts file

```
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Logger, LoggerErrorInterceptor } from 'nestjs-pino';


async function bootstrap() {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
  const PROTOCOL = process.env.PROTOCOL || 'http';
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor());

...
  await app.listen(PORT);
  const serverUrl = `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`;

...
}

bootstrap();
```

The pino logs work correctly in local. However, I want to also send those logs to application insights in azure. How do i do this?
I have already created an app insights resource and know my instrumentation and connection keys.

Comment: Install required package `npm install applicationinsights`.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`applicationinsights`](https://i.imgur.com/jbKu7Be.png) npm package - `npm install applicationinsights`.

- Import the package and set up Application Insights in the `main.ts` file:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { TelemetryClient } from 'applicationinsights';
import { setupInstrumentation } from 'applicationinsights/NestJs';

async function bootstrap() {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
  const PROTOCOL = process.env.PROTOCOL || 'http';

  // Initialize Application Insights
  const instrumentationKey = 'YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY'; // Replace with your key
  const telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(instrumentationKey);
  setupInstrumentation(telemetryClient);

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });

  // Start Application Insights telemetry
  telemetryClient.trackNodeHttpDependency();

  await app.listen(PORT);
  const serverUrl = `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`;

  console.log(`Application is running on: ${serverUrl}`);
}

bootstrap();
```

- Update the `pinoConfig.ts` file to include the Azure Application Insights transport.

**pinoConfig.ts:**

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Params } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { TelemetryClient } from 'applicationinsights';

config();

// Initialize the Application Insights client
const appInsights = new TelemetryClient(process.env.APP_INSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY);

const pinoConfig: Params = {
  pinoHttp: {
    level: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'debug' : 'info',
    formatters: {
      level: (label, number) => {
        return { level: label };
      },
    },
    customReceivedMessage: function (req, res) {
      return `request ${req.id} received: ${req.method} ${req.url}`;
    },
    customSuccessMessage: function (req, res) {
      return `${req.method} ${req.url} completed`;
    },
    customErrorMessage: function (req, res, err) {
      return `request ${req.id} to ${req.method} ${req.url} errored with status code: ${res.statusCode} message: ${err.message}}`;
    },
    transport: [
      {
        target: 'pino-pretty',
        options: {
          singleLine: true,
          ignore: 'pid,hostname,req.headers,req.remotePort,req.remoteAddress,req,res',
        },
      },
      // Add Azure Application Insights transport
      {
        target: 'pino-azure-appinsights',
        options: {
          client: appInsights,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default pinoConfig;
```

You can find the instrumentation key in `portal>application insights>overview`.

[image]

Check the logs in the app insight>Investigate>Transaction search.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I checked but I don't think there is a 'pino-azure-appinsights' package. Did you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-applicationinsights ?

Comment: Also for the telemetryClient.trackNodeHttpDependency(); It shows an error "NodeClient.d.ts(28, 29): An argument for 'telemetry' was not provided."